# spring-mvc The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. for json post

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to build a springmvc app. On one of the action I want it to take a POST of JSON content. I am sending the following values:

```
POST /TestResults/create.json HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

[ { "test_name": "value1", "test_time": "111"} ]
```

However, when I send it I am getting the following error:

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

My action looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView createTest(@RequestBody TestResult test_result) {
```

When I change the action to be`public ModelAndView createTest(@RequestBody String test_result) {` the action does succeed but I am using "String" at that time.

Is it possible to know what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: shouldn't it be `Mapping(value="/create.json" ...)` (with the .json extension)?  also, is your servlet at `/TestResults` (ie servlet-mapping in web.xml)?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are receiving is a JSON array. A JSON array unless you have a custom deserializer cannot be mapped to a type like `TestResult`, unless it's some subtype of `Collection`. You'll want to use something like

```
public ModelAndView createTest(@RequestBody List<TestResult> testResults) {
```

For `@RequestBody String` it works because all Spring has to do is read from the request body and convert the bytes into a `String`.